# Finding and classifying the equilibria of a model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, roots, stability-in-odes

I have to find the equilibria of the following model: $$\frac{dI}{dt} = \frac{\alpha \beta I (1-I)}{\alpha I + r} - \mu I - \frac{\gamma I}{A+I}$$

and then find the conditions for their existence. For nontrivial equilibria, $f(I)$ gets a little messy and $f'(I)$ gets even messier. Before I undertake finding/classifying nontrivial roots using the quadratic equation, is there an easier way to find/classify the equilibria of this equation?

Comment: Clearly, but finding nontrivial $I*$ for $\frac{dI}{dt} = 0$ is rather difficult, and further classifying them by seeing the behavior of $f^\prime (I*)$ is even more difficult (the point of my question).

Comment: It doesn't look that difficult to me. Maybe show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the trivial solution $I=0$, you can simplify the equation to

$$ \frac{\beta (1-I)}{I + \frac{r}{\alpha}} - \mu - \frac{\gamma}{A+I} = 0 $$

Multiplying through by the common denominator

$$ \beta(1-I)(A+I) - \mu\left(I+\frac{r}{\alpha}\right)(A+I) - \gamma\left(I+\frac{r}{\alpha}\right) = 0 $$

It's just straight algebra from here to reduce this down to a quadratic equation.

If you don't feel like solving it, try finding the determinant to see how many roots it has.

Before you get deterred, remember that everything but $I$ is just a bunch of constants. Try reducing them to simpler constants if you can.